# Вывести запись минимальной даты для каждого продавца, без подзапроса

Tags: sql, oracle

Подскажите,как вывести записи, где rank = 1, без подзапроса.
Или не используя rank вывести одну минимальную дату для каждого продавца.

```
  select p.kto_prodal, 
       sum(p.kol_vo*g.goodds_cost) qq,
       min(p.p_data) over(PARTITION BY p.p_data),
       rank() over(PARTITION BY p.kto_prodal order by p.p_data  ) rmk
  from prodal p 
  join goods g
    on (g.goods_id = p.tovar_id)
 where p.tovar_id = 1
 group by p.kto_prodal, p.p_data;


7369    14400   30-03-21 06:50:10,000000000 1
7369    11200   01-04-21 01:43:16,000000000 2
7369    12000   01-04-21 18:23:56,000000000 3
7369    6400    10-04-21 11:06:28,000000000 4
7369    9600    12-04-21 04:06:35,000000000 5
7369    15200   13-04-21 12:24:53,000000000 6
7369    14400   03-05-21 16:38:25,000000000 7
7369    6400    04-05-21 07:08:18,000000000 8
7369    800 06-05-21 16:45:41,000000000 9
7369    13600   07-05-21 12:47:54,000000000 10
......
7369    9600    21-03-22 00:03:48,000000000 73
7499    2400    22-03-21 06:16:36,000000000 1
7499    5600    23-03-21 05:45:42,000000000 2
7499    8800    26-03-21 06:44:15,000000000 3
7499    15200   07-04-21 13:50:14,000000000 4
7499    11200   07-04-21 16:59:40,000000000 5
7499    9600    11-04-21 09:09:13,000000000 6
.......
```

вот нужное, но используется подзапрос

```
 SELECT * FROM (select p.kto_prodal, 
       sum(p.kol_vo*g.goodds_cost) qq,
       min(p.p_data) over(PARTITION BY p.p_data),
       rank() over(PARTITION BY p.kto_prodal order by p.p_data  ) rmk
  from prodal p 
  join goods g
    on (g.goods_id = p.tovar_id)
 where p.tovar_id = 1
 group by p.kto_prodal, p.p_data) where rmk=1;


7369    14400   30-03-21 06:50:10,000000000 1
7499    2400    22-03-21 06:16:36,000000000 1
7521    14400   22-03-21 20:29:04,000000000 1
7566    4000    31-03-21 07:28:05,000000000 1
7654    5600    23-03-21 07:36:34,000000000 1
7698    8000    26-03-21 02:31:16,000000000 1
7782    4000    28-03-21 10:51:38,000000000 1
7788    13600   30-03-21 01:35:14,000000000 1
7839    9600    27-03-21 01:50:28,000000000 1
7844    7200    27-03-21 07:46:35,000000000 1
7876    1600    25-03-21 09:31:46,000000000 1
7900    5600    22-03-21 23:12:43,000000000 1
7902    5600    24-03-21 04:49:47,000000000 1
7934    7200    26-03-21 21:35:27,000000000 1
```

Comment: Вы делаете что-то не то. Пояснните смысл приведённых в вопросе запросов. Привидите минимальный пример данных и ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вывести запись минимальной даты для каждого продавца, без подзапроса

Просто берем и выводим продавца и минимальную дату. Без подзапроса. Группировка только по продавцу.

```
select p.kto_prodal, 
       min(p.p_data)
  from prodal p 
 where …
 group by p.kto_prodal
```

Comment: Группировка только по продавцу помогла